# Proof that for infinite sets, bijections and injections are equivalent

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Online I found the following statement that for $X$ an infinite set, if there is a bijection from $X$ to $\mathbb{N}$ this is equivalent to there is an injection from $X$ to $\mathbb{N}$. How would I prove this?

**Attempt:** The fact that if there is a bijection it is also an injection is true by definition of bijection. Beyond that, I don't know how to demonstrate that an injection is equivalent to a bijection for an infinite set $X$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: "*If there is a bijection from $X$ to $\Bbb N$ then there is an injection from $X$ to $\Bbb N$*"...  the bijection whose existence is guaranteed in the hypothesis is by definition of what a bijection is also an injection as well.  "*how to demonstrate an injection is equivalent to a bijection*"  That is false.  The converse of the statement is false for general infinite sets.  Just because an injection exists between infinite sets $X$ and $Y$ does not imply a bijection exists, nor does it imply that the injection talked about is a bijection itself either.

Comment: That being said, $\Bbb N$ is something of a special case as it can be thought of as "the smallest" infinite set in a way.  There are still able to be injections from $X$ to $\Bbb N$ which are not bijections (*e.g. the function $f~:~\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ given by $f(n)=2n$ is not surjective but is injective*).

Comment: Would you be able to check my solution @JMoravitz ?

Comment: So is fact 6 incorrect? https://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/a-short-post-on-countability-and-uncountability/

Answer (score 0):

We start off by observing that $X$ can not be uncountable as $card(X) \le card(\mathbb{N})$ due to the existence of an injection $f: X \to \mathbb{N}$. However, since $X$ is infinite, it is countable. Hence, $X$ is in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$.